# Can a batsman be caught from their elbow?

Tags: rules, cricket

Ball hits elbow or below elbow of batsman and raises in the air. The ball is then directly caught by fielder. Is he out or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost certainly not out. Refer to [Law 33.1 "Out Caught"](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws/caught)

> The striker is out Caught if a ball delivered by the bowler, not being a No ball, touches his/her bat without having previously been in contact with any fielder, and is subsequently held by a fielder as a fair catch

and [Law 5.6.2 "Contact with the ball"](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws/the-bat)

> contact between the ball and any of 5.6.2.1 to 5.6.2.4
>
> 5.6.2.1 the bat itself
>
> 5.6.2.2 the batsman’s hand holding the bat
>
> 5.6.2.3 any part of a glove worn on the batsman’s hand holding the bat
>
> 5.6.2.4 any additional materials permitted under 5.4
>
> shall be regarded as the ball striking or touching the bat or being struck by the bat.

"The elbow" is not listed in any of the points in 5.6.2 so the ball does not count as having struck the bat, so the batsman cannot be out caught. The batsman could potentially be out LBW if the ball would have struck the wicket - despite the name, this does not have to involve the leg.

Answer (score -2):

If the batsmen is wearing an arm guard, and the ball hits the arm guard and caught he is adjudged out caught

---

**Edit**

It is listed below according to rule 5.6.2.4 additional materials

> contact between the ball and any of 5.6.2.1 to 5.6.2.4
>
> 5.6.2.1 the bat itself
>
> 5.6.2.2 the batsman’s hand holding the bat
>
> 5.6.2.3 any part of a glove worn on the batsman’s hand holding the bat
>
> 5.6.2.4 any additional materials permitted under
> 5.4 shall be regarded as the ball striking or touching the bat or being struck by the bat.

Comment: Which law are you basing this answer on?

Comment: @PhilipKendall 5.6.2.4 additional materials

Comment: @PhilipKendall  i have edited my answer to clarify your doubt

Comment: 5.4 refers to protective material on the bat itself, not protective equipment for the batsman.

Comment: @PhilipKendall this is based on MCC law 5.6

Comment: Which of the points you've listed are you saying includes an arm guard? It's clearly not 5.6.2.1, 5.6.2.2 or 5.6.2.3, and 5.6.2.4 refers to 5.4 which is about protective coverings *on the bat*, not on the batsman. None of those seem to me to refer to an arm guard.